# Why does $D_{4m} \cong C_2\times D_{2m}$ fail for $m$ even?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've read through the first proof at [Show that $D_{12}$ is isomorphic to $D_6\times C_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98343/show-that-d-12-is-isomorphic-to-d-6-times-c-2) . I don't see why a similar argument wouldn't work for $D_{16} \cong D_8 \times C_2$. (or any $D_{4m})$

I know $D_{16}\not \cong C_8\times C_2$ since $D_{16}$ has an element of order $8$ (namely $r$), while $C_2\times D_8$ the maximal order is $4$.

#### Proof

I'll try to repeat the proof in the linked question, I don't see where it fails here.

If we want to prove $D_{16}\cong D_8\times C_2$, then we are looking for a $N, M \trianglelefteq D_{16}$ such that $NM = D_{16}, N\cap M = 1$ and $N\cong C_2, M\cong D_8$.

Let $N = \{1, r^4\}$ then $N = Z(D_{16}) \trianglelefteq D_{16}$. And $N\cong C_2$

Now since $D_{8} = \langle r,f \mid r^4=f^2= 1 \quad\text{and}\quad rfr=f\rangle$ let $M = \langle r^2, f \mid (r^2)^4 = f^2 = 1 \quad\text{and}\quad r^2fr^2= f\rangle$ then $M \cong D_8$ while $M\trianglelefteq D_{16}$ since it is a subgroup of index 2.

All these seem to combine into the needed conditions which lead to conclude $D_{16}\cong M\times N \cong D_8\times C_2$.

Where is the error?

Comment: $r^2fr^2=f$ does not hold in $D_{16}$.

Comment: Why not? The usual condition seems to be $rf = f r^{-1}$ which is equivalent to $rfr = f$, but then $r(rfr)r = f$ or $r^2 f r^2 =f$?

Comment: Oops, I think I did $r^2fr^{-2}$. Too used to conjugation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that in the case $2\mid m$ the center $N$ is a subgroup of the group generated by $r^2$ and $f$. You do get that $D_{4m}$ has a subgroup $M$ isomorphic to $D_{2m}$ (this is obvious from their realization as groups of symmetries of regular polygons). But, this time $N\le M$.

Hint: The center $Z(C_2\times D_m)=C_2\times Z(D_m)$. What do you know about the center $Z(D_m)$.

Comment: Ok, that was easier than I thought. It fails the $N\cap M = 1$ condition. Thanks!

Comment: Correct. Well done, Dieter.