# D$_6$ isomorphic to S$_3$ cross C$_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I believe this claim to be true but Im not sure how it can be as when i write out the elements of S$_3$ cross C$_2$ I do not get any elements of order 6, and yet for D$_6$ we must have r$^6$ = 1 and 6 is the lowest such power of r such that it equals 1.

For S$_3$ cross C$_2$ i have: 
((123),1) = 3
((132),1) = 3
(12),1) = 2
((23),1) = 2
((13),1) = 2
(1,1) = 1
And 
((123),y) = 4
((132),y) = 4
((12),y) = 2
((23),y) = 2
((13),y) = 2
(1,y) = 2

Ive calculated the orders of the above and put them to the right of the equals sign of each element. Im hoping someone could correct me on either which element has order 6, or why that is not necessary for the isomorphism to exist.

Thanks!

Comment: It isn't a direct product, $D_n=C_n\rtimes C_2$.

Comment: This is correct. Whenever $n$ is even, say $n=2k$, the rotation by 180 degrees ($=r^k$) is in the center of $D_n$. If furthermore $k$ is odd, then all the rotations of $D_n$ are combinations of $r^2$ and $r^k$. Obviously we can select a reflection in $D_n$ in such a way that it is also a symmetry of the regular $k$-gon gotten by including every other vertex. These facts imply that
$$\langle r,s\rangle=\langle r^2,s\rangle\times\langle r^k\rangle.$$ Here $6\equiv2\pmod 4$, so both the conditions hold giving the claim.
Furthermore, I'm sure we have covered this already on the site.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98343/11619). Indeed, for some heretics the subscript $n$ in $D_n$ indicates the order of the group. For such people $D_6$ is what you would call $D_3\cong S_3$, and $D_{12}$ is your $D_6$. Anyway, the argument is contained and generalized in those answers.

Comment: If there is something that needs clarification, do edit the question/comment here. This is a live possibility! We can then reopen and add more details. If someone is itching to add another proof for this fact right away, they can do so in the linked question (or act to get this reopened and wait).

Comment: Oh, and +1 for showing your work.

Comment: I think you should reconsider your calculation of the order of $((123),y)$.

Comment: And, finally, the order of $((123),y)$ is six, not four.

Comment: @Gerry Do you agree with my choice of duplicate target? Some answers there seem to be at the level of this OP, so I closed. But if you disagree, I'm happy to reconsider.

Comment: Ahhh yes, i knew i calculated that one incorrectly. This is a direct product though right? They arent exactly subgroups of the same group and that notation is pretty standard i believe for direct product

Comment: @Jyrki yes, I think there's enough material at that target to qualify, and OP can always ask for clarification.