# Symmetries of the dihedral groups $D_n$ and $D_{nh}$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetry, dihedral-groups

According to my lecture book (Linear Representations of Finite Groups by Serre), the dihedral group $D_n$ consists of $n$ rotations and $n$ reflections in the plane that preserve a regular polygon with $n$ vertices. He later writes that if $D_n$ is realized as a group of rotations and reflections of $3$-space then $D_{nh}$ can be realized as the group generated by $D_n$ and the reflection through the origin.
**Edit**: The book mentions that the order of $D_{nh}$ is $4n$ and it is the product $D_n\times I$ where $I$ is the group $\{1,\iota\}$ with $\iota^2=1$.

First of all, *I would like to know what he means by "3-space"*, since a polygon is a 2-dimensional object.

Second, *I would like to be sure that I understand the groups correctly*. I understand $D_n$ to have the $n$ reflections where the $n$ symmetry elements are *lines* in the plane, so that for example the 4 symmetry elements of reflections of a regular square are the ones depicted on the figure below on the left. I then assume that $D_{nh}$ is what we get if we add a reflection with the origin as the symmetry element, as depicted on the right. Is that correct?
[image]

**Edit**: I know many here hate screenshots, but from the comments I think it makes sense in this case.
[image]

Comment: Could you pass some lines and add emphasis on your questions? use *

Comment: @JulesBesson, something like that?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, according to the book, $D_{nh}$ has order $4n$. He defines it as the group generated by $D_n$ and the reflection through the origin. It can be written as $D_n\times I$, where $I$ is the group given by $\{1,\iota\}$ with $\iota^2=1$.

Comment: Even though $|D_n|=2n$ I don't think you can translate that to $D_{nh}=2hn$. I think $D_{nh}$ is just a name the group has been given because we add a reflection through a horizontal line, $h$ (not sure, but that is my guess).

Comment: You should give a proper definition of the group $D_{nh}$. The notation is misleading, suggesting that it is a dihedral group $D_m$ for $m=nh$. Do you have a link to the book, so that we can check this?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, then maybe it is not called a dihedral group (I might then have made a mistake in the headline). I believe it is supposed to be a _different_ group than the dihedral group $D_n$.

Comment: I see. But then the notation $D_{nh}$ is really misleading. The group is $D_n\times C_2$. For $n$ even we have [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98343/show-that-d-12-is-isomorphic-to-d-6-times-c-2), by the way.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I have added a snapshot of the books definition of the group.

Comment: Do you have accesss to the reference he's mentioning?

Comment: @JulesBesson, yes: 5.3(a): "One takes for rotations the rotations around the axis Oz, and for reflections, the reflections through n lines of the plane Oxy, these lines forming angles which are multiples of $\pi/n$."